# Presenter layer covered by protocols

Tags: swift, uikit

I try to write loosely coupled code and I wonder if presenter layer in model view presenter architecture pattern should be covered by protocols?

I have Presenter like this:

```
class WorkoutPresenter {

 weak var delegate: WorkoutPresenterDelegate?

 init(delegate: WorkoutPresenterDelegate) {
   self.delegate = delegate
 }
 
  func startWorkout() {
   .
   .
 }

 func endWorkout() {
 .
 .
 .
 }
}
```

And later when we initialize this presenter in view controller, don't we create tightly coupled?

```
class WorkoutViewController {

 lazy var presenter = WorkoutPresenter(delegate: self)

}
```

Should I use protocols in presenter? Something like this:

```
protocol WorkoutProtocols {
func startWorkout()
func endWorkout()
}
```

and later conform to these protocols

```
class WorkoutPresenter: WorkoutProtocols {
.
.
. 
}
class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {

 lazy var presenter: WorkoutProtocols = WorkoutPresenter()   

}
```

and now we have loosely coupled? Please correct me if I am wrong

I ask this questions because I've seen different approaches to this in web, and I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Either is fine. The benefit to having an init with delegate is that you don't need to remember to set the delegate somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Ok, so using Presenter without protocols is equally good as using Presenter with protocols? I wonder if using without protocols doesn't break letter D in SOLID, so The Dependency Inversion Principle. I mean using Presenter without protocols brings situations where high level module depends on low level modules, not abstractions.

Comment: But using protocols in presenter, later when we call it in VC we depends on abstractions. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You have two protocols WorkoutPresenterDelegate & WorkoutProtocols. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about. If you need to call the methods and don't care who you're calling them on you need to agree to protocols. If the type is known to have the methods you don't..

Comment: I ask if Presenter in MVP architecture should be based on protocols, and later create it like in code above (lazy var presenter: WorkoutProtocols = WorkoutPresenter()) or maybe should be based on its own methods and later create it in vc like in first example  lazy var presenter = WorkoutPresenter()

Comment: Protocols will allow changes later. If you want some other presenter to be set to var presenter. In your case you are creating the instance in vc, so you know what the object will be and there is no need to decouple unless you want to subclass and replace the presenter type. as for D.I.P. I think technically you deviate, but I don't see a problem doing it either way in your case. Honestly, either is an abstraction from vc..